# Question about quotient of separable spaces

Tags: functional-analysis

Exercise: Let $E$ a Banach space separable and $F$ a closed subspace of $E$. Prove that $E/F$ is separable.

My idea: Since $E$ is separable then exist $D_1\subset E$ numerable and dense and Since F is closed then $F=\bar{F}$. Moreover $F$ is separable, beacuse every subset of separable space is separable.

We know that
\begin{equation*}
E/F=\{[x]: x\in F\}
\end{equation*}

Maybe, We can find a numerable and dense subset consisting of equivalences clases. But, I don't know how to relate the quotient $E/F$ in the proof.

Comment: If $(x_n)_{n \in \Bbb{N}}$ is dense in $E$, then $([x_n])_{n \in \Bbb{N}}$ is dense in $E/F$. See if you can prove it!

Comment: Hint: $||[x_n]|| \leq ||x_n||$

Comment: I would like to mention that subsets of separable metric spaces need not be separable (this fact is usually expressed saying that separability is not hereditary). However, this is true for closed subspaces in separable Banach spaces.

Comment: @DavideRavasini subsets of separable metric spaces **are** separable.